# Finding max-height of an element

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way to find out the pre-defined `max-height` (css property) of an element?

I want to find the height with `.height()` and compare with css `max-height` and add add class if max-height reached.

Comment: Have you tried `.css('max-height')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv').css('max-height');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F9DPh/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.css('max-height')` but if you want a number you have to drop "px" (or other unit) part:

```
parseInt($("element").css('max-height'),10)
```

Comment: Add `|| 0` to consider the possibility that `max-height` was not defined